# Work and Time Problem, machines

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Three accounting machines and 2 operators are finish in one day the work done by 10 clerks in two days. How many machines would be required to do in one day the work done by 40 clerks in one day?

I know that

```
work done by 3 accounting machines and 2 operators = work done by 10 clerks
```

but it takes 1 day for the first and 2 days for the latter.

How can I represent this problem by algebraic means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reality then, the work done by the 10 cleaks is done by 20 clearks, because they need double the time.
You want to be the timeframe in steps of 1.
Also the problem is, do you get additional operators per machine?
If not there is no real solution.
Well suppose you can fully use additional machines, then its kinda easy:

3x + 2z = 20y

6x + 4z = 40y

where x=machines, z=operators and y=clerk

z=0 if 2 operators can magically work on a trillion machines ;-)

Comment: So it takes 6 machines to finish the work done by 40 clerks in one day.

Comment: yes, but only if you get additional operators, or they somehow "wait" for their machines, i.e. they have a lot of free time to manage 6 machines.